# Iterating ng-model? Is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I would like to make a loop that can be automatically initiated at first empty values in the input and then complement them consecutively. However, I do not know how to do it in angularjs using ng-model.
Well, I have a html file

```
<input type="text" id="pin" ng-model="inputData.pin" />
 <input type="text" id="pin2" ng-model="inputData.pin2" />
```

And I would controller instead of writing

```
$scope.inputData = { pin : '' };
$scope.inputData = { pin2 : '' };
```

for automatic loop

```
for (var key in receivedData) {
                for (var detailKey in receivedData[key]) {
                    $scope.inputData = { detailKey : '' };
                }
            }
```

when detailKey is in sequence pin, pin2.

Currently, this does not work. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have misunderstood how to assign a value to an object -- you must [treat it like an associative array](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html).

In your example you are redefining the entire property `$scope.inputData` within each iteration by giving it an object literal that has a single key `detailKey` whose value is an empty string (`''`).

What you instead want to do is define a *new* property on the object, not 'overwrite' the object itself:

```
for (var key in receivedData) {
    for (var detailKey in receivedData[key]) {
        $scope.inputData[detailKey] = '';
    }
}
```

You can then iterate through the keys represented in this object within your Angular template using the `ng-repeat` directive, taking each key from `inputData` and binding their value to an `<input>` element. This will create `n` `<input>` elements where `(n === Object.keys(inputData).length)`.

```
<input type="text" class="pin"
       ng-repeat="key in inputData"
       ng-model="inputData[key]" />
```

*Note:* you cannot have an ID that is used more than once within the same document. I have changed each `<input>` element to have a **class** 'pin' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do `$scope.inputData = receivedData;` ?

Currently what you are doing is reassigning inputData to an object with a static key of detailKey every loop iteration.

Comment: Ok, actually I do so, however, will not work to me because it considers it detailKey for a variable and not the key from the array.
I would like to make it ..detailKey treated successively as pin, pin2

Comment: Look at sdgluck's answer below in that case.